# Grouping results with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list from HTML like this;

```
<ul>
    <li data="foo">a</li>
    <li data="foo">b</li>
    <li data="bar">c</li>
    <li data="foo">d</li>
</ul>
```

and i want to hide this ul and create another which output is like this;

```
<div>
    <h1>foo</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>d</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>bar</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can i do with jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the data loaded from JavaScript, or do you need to extract it from HTML?

Comment: I have only HTML, but i can convert to array. It's not problem. The problem is grouping like that i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a javascript solution then try

```
var map = {};
$('ul li').each(function () {
    var data = $(this).attr('data'),
        array = map[data] = map[data] || [];
    array.push(this);
});
$('ul').remove()

var $ct = $('body');
$.each(map, function (key, item) {
    var $item = $('<div><h1>' + key + '</h1><ul></ul></div>');
    $item.find('ul').append(item);
    $item.appendTo($ct)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DJ9wy/)